# Reusable Workflow as dependency of multiple workflows

Tags: github

I have a workflow that

- builds a Docker image with build tools
- compiles and tests with coverage analysis
- compiles and tests with memory correctness check

The second and third step use the image produced in the first.

Is there a way to split this into three workflows (described in different files) so that the Docker image is still only built once, and the other checks are run after?